# Firebase Database issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to query to my firabse database which is having data like below image.

[image]

I would like to authenticate user on the basis of userEmail and password.

How can I make a query here?

Comment: You might use FirebaseAuth for authentication and for query, you can use valuEventListeners... Refer [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: I want to make query by usertype as well.

Comment: Then you should follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51221002/9855551) by Peter.

Comment: `Firebase` document & (`FirebaseAuth` section) is always your friend tho...Might be a closed thread.

Answer (score 1):

you should use firebase authentication. it will handle that for you. You can 
also use security rules to give permissions to certain type of accounts only https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: I want to create user with usertype as well. Auth will create with email and password only.

Comment: you still ave to use firebase auth. look at Alex Mamo's answer

Answer (score 1):

For handling authentication, you should use FirebaseAuth. Refer [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

For querying data once, you can use this

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users")
 .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This listens for the data only once and gives it to you in dataSnapshot.
        // Use this code to get the userEmail.
        // String userEmail = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("userEmail"));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To query according to the `userType`, then try the following:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").orderByChild("userType").equalTo("Child").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  String id=dataSnapshot.child("id").getValue().toString();
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Using the query `orderByChild` you will be able to retrieve the data related to the result of that query.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you should definitely implement [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and change your database structure a little bit by adding the `uid` as unique identifier between users. So your database structure should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- users
         |
         --- uid
              |
              --- userEmail: "mayank@gmail.com"
              |
              --- userPassword: "123456"
              |
              --- userType: "Child"
```

If you don't use a database structure like this, you'll end up overriding one user after another. To get the `uid`, you simply need to use the following line of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

And in the end, to query your database, you should use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("users").orderByChild("userType").equalTo("Child");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

The result of the query, will be all the children from your database.

Comment: How will I create a user with userType as "Child" or "Parent using firebase Authentication? It is allowed to pass only username and password while creating the user. For authentication also, I can pass only username and password.

Comment: You cannot add `userType` as a property in the FirebaseUser object, you need to create your own UserModel class that can hold more properties.

Comment: You can also wait for other answers but if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!